# Add elements dynamically from selected combo box value in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I would like to add a text box when the value "LIKE" is selected from combo box and two date pickers when value "BETWEEN" is selected.

Right now I am able to read the selected value using `ng-change` method, but I am not able to figure out how to add elements based on selected drop down value.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Text Box</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('controllerAsExample', []).controller('SettingsController1', function ($scope)
            {
                $scope.comboBox = []
                $scope.addDropDown = function ()
                {
                    $scope.comboBox.push('');
                }
                $scope.deleteDropDown = function (index)
                {
                    $scope.comboBox.splice(index, 1);
                }
                $scope.changedValue = function (item) 
                {
                    alert(item);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="controllerAsExample">
        <div id="ctrl-as-exmpl" ng-controller="SettingsController1">

            <ul>
                <button ng-click="addDropDown()">add</button>
                <button ng-click="deleteDropDown()">Delete</button>
                <li ng-repeat="dropDown in comboBox track by $index">
                    <select ng-model="valueSelected" ng-change="changedValue(valueSelected)">
                        <optgroup>
                            <option value="LIKE">LIKE</option>
                            <option value="BETWEEN">BETWEEN</option>
                            <option value="EXISTS">EXISTS</option>
                            <option value="Like">IN</option>
                            <option value="NOT">NOT</option>
                            <option value="OR">OR</option>
                            <option value="ISNULL">ISNULL</option>
                            <option value="UNIQUE">UNIQUE</option>
                            <option value="=">=</option>
                            <option value="!=">!=</option>
                            <option value=">">></option>
                            <option value="<"><</option>
                            <option value=">=">>=</option>
                            <option value="<="><=</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

Answer (score 1):

You have ng-model already set on your select, so just use the built in directives to display what you want when the model matches.  You can use: ngShow/ngHide, ngIf, etc., but probably ngSwitch is the best fit for this application.

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cPmFWNLaME6gSoyUnflB?p=preview)

```
<select ng-model="valueSelected">
  <option value="like">LIKE</option>
  <option value="between">BETWEEN</option>
  <option value="exists">EXISTS</option>
</select>
<div ng-switch on="valueSelected">
  <div ng-switch-when="like">I show when LIKE is selected</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="between">I show when BETWEEN is selected</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="exists">I show when EXISTS is selected</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>I show by default</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I add dom element like text box using ng-switch

Comment: Just put whatever you want to display inside the the div with the corresponding ng-switch-when directive.

Comment: How do I choose range date picker when between is selected. Is there any built-in directive for date picker?

Comment: No, but there are [3rd party directives](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angular%20date%20range%20picker).  Here's an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080708/ui-bootstrap-datepicker-force-a-re-render-of-a-datepicker/30101624#30101624) I provided to use UI Bootstrap's datepicker as a range picker.

Comment: I have downloaded a thirdparty dateRangePicker from this link:https://github.com/RGkevin/datetimeRangePicker   How do I install or use it in Netbeans IDE.

Comment: I'm not a Netbeans user, but if you've downloaded the files, you can use it the same way you would in any IDE by adding it to your project source files and including a script tag in your file.