# How to dynamically set min date and max date in date picker angular js with bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using two date picker:

1. start date
2. end-date

I need to set max date in start date based in end-date value and 
min date in end-date based in start-date value

How to dynamically change the min and max value based on the date change in the date picker

I am using angular date picker with bootstrap 3

Comment: Just set minDate and maxDate to the value from the model the other DatePicker is manipulating. The little eye you can see next to the `minDate` and `maxDate` [settings](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) mean there is a watch to handle changes to the value

Comment: could you please provide an example.I need dynamically changing the min date and max date. Static min date and max date is working for me

Comment: I haven't done much AngularJS lately so that would take me too much time. If you could provide me a base [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with both DatePicker set up (without the min / max validation) I might be able to quickly showcase what I meant.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear in my first comment : let's say the first DatePicker is bound to the model field `$scope.startDate`, which is initialized to `null` until a Date is picked. Then the second DatePicker could be defined with a `minDate='startDate'` argument. At first that would not impose any constraint since `minDate='null'` is the default value and doesn't change behavior. However, as soon as a date is picked in the first DatePicker, `$scope.startDate` would be updated and a constraint relative to that date applied on the second DatePicker.

Comment: please find the fiddler with the code https://jsfiddle.net/070dzLev/1/

Comment: Thanks ; it looks like what I was suggesting and I can't find anything wrong with it, sorry. Here's an [updated version that integrates better with jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/070dzLev/2/) if it can help anyone figure this out.

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot ! I think you've set your constraints wrong : the startDate's max should be the endDate, and the endDate's min the startDate as you stated in your post, but the code implement the opposite. I don't think that will resolve your problem, but it might avoid further confusion.

Comment: The binding to the startDate and endDate is not working see the fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/070dzLev/3/

Comment: Your bindings are oustide of the ng-app div, that's why they don't work. I've verified that the date what correctly mapped, but I still see no validation behaviour. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/070dzLev/4/) (I've also fixed the min/max confusion)

Comment: So, [it starts doing things](https://jsfiddle.net/070dzLev/5/) if we initialize the start and end dates as `Date`s rather than `null` ; the validation kicks in but always with the initial values.

Comment: Did you guys check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080708/ui-bootstrap-datepicker-force-a-re-render-of-a-datepicker it seems pretty similar

Answer (score 2):

You can set the the `min and max` attributes for the two date pickers in the following way.

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date1" max="{{date2 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
<input type="date" ng-model="date2" min="{{date1 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is for singleDatePicker:

```
{
    singleDatePicker: true,
    maxDate:  moment(), //this for current date
    minDate : moment().subtract(1, 'days'), // this is for previous date
    locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    }
}
```